# How to render a string of html dom elements as regular dom elements in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, string

I am trying to iterate over the following string so I can split it and replace petName, himHer, etc. with different words depending on specific information:

> An FeLV / FIV test was performed on petName. The results are listed below:
>
> - 1FeLV results: Negative
> - 2FIV results: Negative
>
> Following exposure to either virus, it can take 1 to 3 months for an infection to develop for himHer. One negative test for FELV or FIV does not guarantee that a cat is truly negative. Due to lag time between a potential initial infection and the development of positive test results, retesting for confirmation of negative FIV and FeLV status may be recommended in the future.

I'm about to do that, however what I am struggling with is rendering the finished string to the page (I am using react) so that it will be interpreted, not as a string, but as html.

I have this function, which replaces the appropriate words with the ones I need to dynamically fill in. It is working just find:

```
export const stringToHTML = ( servicesArr, pronounsObject, petName ) => { 
  console.log(servicesArr)
  let dynamicBlurb = servicesArr.map((sA, i) => {
    console.log(sA)
    let replaceWords = sA.domBlurb.split("petName").join(petName).split("heShe").join(pronounsObject.heShe).split("himHer").join(pronounsObject.himHer).split("hisHers").join(pronounsObject.hisHers).split("hisHer").join(pronounsObject.hisHer);
    console.log(replaceWords)
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(replaceWords, 'text/html')
    sA.cleanBlurb = doc.body
    console.log(sA.cleanBlurb)
    return sA

  });
  return dynamicBlurb
}
```

This is my map statement where the function is called that I am trying to get to render the dom elements (basically I want it to ignore the fact that it is a string):

```
{stringToHTML(
    props.standardProcArr,
    pronounsObject,
    props.petName
    ).map((iPIB, i) => {
        console.log(iPIB)
        console.log(iPIB.cleanBlurb)
        return (
         <>
          <li>{iPIB.cleanBlurb.outerHTML}</li>
        </>
    );
})}
```

As written, it is rendering the string to the page but I need it to see it, not as a string, but as html. If I do pass it in as html rather than a string, I get the error "Objects are not valid react children"

I have tried using domParser and am able to get it to return html, however React throws an error when I try to render it, since it is an object.